# ALSA output to two dmix devices simultaneously using a multi device

Tags: linux, usb, audio, alsa

I am trying to play audio to two hardware devices simultaneously, `megalodon` and `analog`, using two dmix devices. `megalodon` is a USB headset, `analog` is just the 3.5mm port on my computer. When I route audio to the dmix for `megalodon` called `headsetout` and also route it directly to `analog`, it works just fine. However, if I route it to both `headsetout` and `analogout` (the dmix for `analog`) I get the error `ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable`. If I output only to `analogout`, either by playing to it directly or by creating a multi-output device that only outputs to `analogout` it works just fine.

How can I make output to both `headsetout` and `analogout` work properly?

Here is the relevant parts of my asound.conf to make it easier to understand what's happening.
In addition, I have tried both wrapping the dmix devices in a `plug` device as they are in the below config, as well as using them directly, to no avail.

```
pcm.megalodon {
    type hw
    card "Megalodon"
}

pcm.analog {
    type hw
    card "PCH"
    device 0
}

#Play to headphones and earbuds
pcm.splitout {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "headsetout" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "analog" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }

    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]
    ]
}

#Theoretically play to headphones and earbuds
#this one doesn't work
#error:
#ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable
#aplay: set_params:1204: Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available
#
#However, analogout works when used on it's own
pcm.splitout1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type multi
        slaves {
            a { channels 2 pcm "headsetout" }
            b { channels 2 pcm "analogout" }
        }
        bindings {
            0 { slave a channel 0 }
            1 { slave a channel 1 }
            2 { slave b channel 0 }
            3 { slave b channel 1 }
        }

    }
    ttable [
        [ 1 0 1 0 ]
        [ 0 1 0 1 ]
    ]
}

#dmix output for headphones
pcm.headsetout {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 192959
        ipc_key_add_uid true
        ipc_perm 0666
        slave {
            pcm "megalodon"
            rate 48000
            channels 6

            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_time 0
            buffer_size 16384
        }
    }
}

#dmix output for analog jack (3.5mm)
pcm.analogout {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 3785682
        ipc_key_add_uid true
        ipc_perm 0666
        slave {
            pcm "analog"
            rate 48000
            channels 2

            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_time 0
            buffer_size 16384
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both devices actually support 44.1 kHz?

Comment: Looks like `megalodon`  actually only supports 48 kHz, but `analog` supports both. Changing both to 48000 didn't solve the problem, but I've updated the config in the question to match the change. Interestingly this actually changed the error messing to `aplay: xrun:1552: read/write error, state = PREPARED` when testing `splitout1` with aplay, but all the other devices still work.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just try throwing different plugins at the problem and I was able to fix it with upmix. I was under the impression that `type plug` would have handled this for me, but that is not the case.

Before:

```
#dmix output for headphones
pcm.headsetout {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type dmix
        ipc_key 192959
        ipc_key_add_uid true
        ipc_perm 0666
        slave {
            pcm "megalodon"
            rate 48000
            channels 6

            period_time 0
            period_size 1024
            buffer_time 0
            buffer_size 16384
        }
    }
}
```

After:

```
#dmix output for headphones
pcm.headsetout {
    type upmix
    slave.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
            type dmix
            ipc_key 192959
            ipc_key_add_uid true
            ipc_perm 0666
            slave {
                pcm "megalodon"
                rate 48000
                channels 6

                period_time 0
                period_size 1024
                buffer_time 0
                buffer_size 16384
            }
        }
    }
}
```